# SpringBoot/Spring Cloud Config Client multiple application contexts (root & servlet) with RefreshScope annotated beans

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a couple of questions regarding Spring Cloud Config in a web application.

**Context**

I'm working on an SpringBoot web application where I have a **Root application context (parent)** and a **Servlet application context (child)**, I'm adding Spring Cloud Config capabilities to this application (of course this app connects to a Spring Cloud Config server via http).

When I annotate a bean that is registered in the Root application context with the `RefreshScope` annotation everything works as expected, the problems started when I tried to annotate a spring bean that is registered in the Servlet application context.

**First problem:** an `IllegalStateException` was thrown when the `@RefreshScope` annotated bean in the servlet application context was tried to be accessed, the following is the meaningful part of the stacktrace:

```
ERROR: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'
```

**Solution:** the error above was solved by registering the **refresh** scope to the Servlet application context

```
@Bean
public CustomScopeConfigurer servletCustomScopeConfigurer(org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope refreshScope) {
    CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
    customScopeConfigurer.addScope("refresh", refreshScope);
    return customScopeConfigurer;
}
```

**Question:** Assuming that this way to model a web application is still relevant (I think it is), why I couldn't find any documentation stating that it's necessary to register the **refresh** scope to the servlet application context and I should register the `org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope` bean from the root application context?

**Second problem:** Once I had the **refresh** scope registered in the servlet application context the application started fine, and everything seemed to be working, however when I tried to update a property from the refreshable beans I had mixed results, when I refresh a property that would modify a bean in the root application context I could see the bean being updated, so all good, however when I update a property that would modify a bean in the servlet application context I could set the bean being refreshed but the new property value was not being reflected in the bean.

**Solution:**  After some tests I realised that the `ConfigurableEnvironment` in both contexts are not the same, at some point the parent `ConfigurableEnvironment` is merged to the child `ConfigurableEnvironment` that is how beans in the servlet context get initialised correctly at startup, but when the `ContextRefresher.refresh()` is called by the `RefreshEndpoint` only the parent `ConfigurableEnvironment` is updated, and the child `ConfigurableEnvironment` is not leaving it with the old values, what I did now was to inject the parent `ConfigurableEnvironment` when creating the servlet application context and everything worked as expected, relevant code:

```
@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet(ConfigurableEnvironment parentEnvironment) {
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register(WebConfiguration.class);
    applicationContext.setEnvironment(parentEnvironment);
    dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    return dispatcherServlet;
}
```

**Question:** Again I was surprised by the lack of documentation on the expected behaviour of a Spring application declaring parent and child application contexts, maybe I just didn't find it and it exists and is amazing. Is the approach of setting the parent `ConfigurableEnvironment` to the child servlet context the correct one?

In the **default** case where (parent `ConfigurableEnvironment` NOT set in the servlet context.) would be the fact that the child `ConfigurableEnvironment` is not refreshed if  is intentional or a bug?

If you are still reading this, thanks! Answers to the questions above will be very appreciated!

Hopefully this helps other people dealing with these issues.

Comment: I haven't seen many (any) apps register a separate servlet context.

Comment: @spencergibb that is possibility that this type of application is not relevant any more, which will be surprising to me, but might explain the lack of information about it.